# SOAP method call that takes two objects as arguments

Tags: soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I'm doing a SOAP call to access the method getMailingReports from the below wsdl and can access it just fine. My problem is when I have to use createEmailMailing but have to pass in two arguments that are objects (Mailing and EmailContent). This is from stormpost (pulsepoint) so if anyone has experience with this I'd appreciate it. Below is the wsdl and the SOAP call I'm doing with ColdFusion. Again, this SOAP call works fine, but not sure how to mimic this and use the method createEmailMailing.

http://api.stormpost.datranmedia.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor?wsdl

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soap">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <ns0:username SOAP-ENV:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" xmlns:ns0="http://services.web.stormpost.skylist.com">fakelogin</ns0:username>
                <ns0:password SOAP-ENV:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" xmlns:ns0="http://services.web.stormpost.skylist.com">fakepassword</ns0:password>
            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <ns0:getMailingReports xmlns:ns0="http://services.web.stormpost.skylist.com">
                    <from xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"><cfoutput>#dateFormat(arguments.from, "yyyy-mm-dd")#</cfoutput>T00:00:00.000</from>
                    <to xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"><cfoutput>#dateFormat(arguments.to, "yyyy-mm-dd")#</cfoutput>T23:00:00.000</to>
                    <type xsi:type="xsd:string">Mailings</type>
                    <channel xsi:type="xsd:string">EMAIL</channel>
                    <listid xsi:type="xsd:int">0</listid>
                    <limit xsi:type="xsd:int">#arguments.numRowsReturned#</limit>
                </ns0:getMailingReports>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfhttp url="https://api.stormpost.datranmedia.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor" method="POST">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(trim(soap))#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8">
        <cfhttpparam type="XML" name="message" value="#trim(soap)#">
    </cfhttp>
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: hey Evik James, I'm using CF9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been learning SOAP and CF myself. I highly recommend [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for testing. It parsed out a sample createEmailMailing request with no problem. Anyplace there's a question mark is where you want to put values to write to the DB.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.web.stormpost.skylist.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <authInfo xsi:type="soap:authentication" xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor">
         <!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">?</username>
         <password xsi:type="xsd:string">?</password>
      </authInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:createEmailMailing soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <mailing xsi:type="soap:Mailing" xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor">
            <!--You may enter the following 37 items in any order-->
            <title xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</title>
            <externalID xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</externalID>
            <comment xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</comment>
            <protocol xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</protocol>
            <campaignID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</campaignID>
            <brandID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</brandID>
            <listID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</listID>
            <conditionOperator xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</conditionOperator>
            <condition1Column xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition1Column>
            <condition1Operator xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition1Operator>
            <condition1Value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition1Value>
            <condition2Column xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition2Column>
            <condition2Operator xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition2Operator>
            <condition2Value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition2Value>
            <condition3Column xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition3Column>
            <condition3Operator xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition3Operator>
            <condition3Value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition3Value>
            <condition4Column xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition4Column>
            <condition4Operator xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition4Operator>
            <condition4Value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition4Value>
            <condition5Column xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition5Column>
            <condition5Operator xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition5Operator>
            <condition5Value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</condition5Value>
            <maxRecipients xsi:type="xsd:int">?</maxRecipients>
            <seeds xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_soapenc_string"/>
            <blockDomains xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_soapenc_string"/>
            <purgeLists xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_xsd_int"/>
            <purgeSuppressionLists xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_xsd_int"/>
            <queueTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">?</queueTime>
            <trackType xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</trackType>
            <openTrackType xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</openTrackType>
            <clickStreamType xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</clickStreamType>
            <advertiserName xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</advertiserName>
            <unsubReportsAddress xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</unsubReportsAddress>
            <unsubReportsSize xsi:type="xsd:int">?</unsubReportsSize>
            <priority xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</priority>
            <additionalLists xsi:type="soap:ArrayOf_xsd_int"/>
         </mailing>
         <content xsi:type="soap:EmailContent" xmlns:soap="http://skylist.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor">
            <!--You may enter the following 16 items in any order-->
            <subject xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</subject>
            <fromEmail xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</fromEmail>
            <fromName xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</fromName>
            <toEmail xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</toEmail>
            <toName xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</toName>
            <replyToEmail xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</replyToEmail>
            <replyToName xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</replyToName>
            <charset xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</charset>
            <encoding xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</encoding>
            <htmlContent xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</htmlContent>
            <textContent xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">?</textContent>
            <unsubContentID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</unsubContentID>
            <replyContentID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</replyContentID>
            <headerContentID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</headerContentID>
            <footerContentID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</footerContentID>
            <forwardToFriendContentID xsi:type="xsd:int">?</forwardToFriendContentID>
         </content>
      </ser:createEmailMailing>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You'll also want to alter one of your params something like:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="createEmailMailing">
```